# Multiple Imputation: If "Pooled" isn't "averaged" then what is it?

Tags: multiple-imputation, pooling

I used MI for a couple variables, and just want to be sure I know what SPSS did when it pooled test statistics.

I've read that "pooled" is not "averaged"...so what is the calculation being done when it pools results?

Maybe it depends on the statistical test?

To be specific, I will be running t-tests, bivariate correlations, linear regression (all of which are MI-support analyses in SPSS 22).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You average the estimates (e.g. the sample means or the regression coefficient estimates). You average the estimated variances or covariance matrices of the estimates, but then you add another term to account for the uncertainty across imputations. See page 4 of http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jls/reprints/miprimer.pdf

Comment: By the way, I'm just assuming that SPSS combines the results in the usual way. To be sure, you'll have to check the SPSS documentation and/or verify the calculations for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Pooled typically refers to a "weighted" average. If you have two samples and estimates of each samples variance is $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ you might consider the pooled estimate:

$$
s^2 = \dfrac{ (n_1-1)s_1^2 + (n_2-1)s_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}$$

Note this is not a simple average which would be $$\dfrac{s_1^2+s_2^2}{2}$$

The idea is that each sample might be based on a different sample size and you want to account for that in your estimate (the estimate that comes from the larger sample size should have more of an impact on your final estimate than the estimate from the smaller sample size).

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question, because in multiple imputation the sample sizes will be the same.

Comment: Not really. I'm currently conducting a multiple imputation analysis with different sample sizes. After initially conducting multiple imputation (10 iterations) on a dataset, I indeed ended up with 10 datasets of equal size. However, I then had to conduct propensity score matching on each imputed dataset, and each one returned a different number of matched-controls. My sub-sample of matched controls therefore varies in size for each imputed dataset.